# Find Canonical Path like C:\Agent17-01\_work\50\s\Test Files

Tags: java

can someone help me to find Canonical Path like `"C:\Agent17-01\_work\50\s\Test Files"`.
 I have created below method to find Canonical path but it gave the path
`"C:\Agent17-01\_work\50\Test Files"`.
\s\ is missing in my method. below is my method code

```
    public static String getRelativePath(String FileName)
    {
        String path =
                null;
        File f = new File("..\\..\\Test Files\\" + FileName);
        try
        {
            path = f.getCanonicalPath();
            System.out.println(path);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
        return path;
    }
```

any help is appreciated
Thanks in advance.

Comment: be careful about using \ this is a escape character, you should use \\ if you want to use the character itself.

Comment: What directory are you running this code from?

Comment: Try "..\\..\\..\\Test Files\\" and "..\\Test Files\\" Either of them should work. Also make sure the file "Test Files" is present in the right directory.

Comment: Hi @cricket_007  My Selenium CI project integration with TFS and both Project and Test Files folder are in different directory. I kept my all files in Test Files folder.

When execution trigger in CI run time it find available TFS agent (TFs agent could be like C:\Agent17-01\_work\50\s) get project source code from tfs deployed and start execution.


Tfs store folder in this path - "C:\Agent17-01\_work\50\s\Test Files"
My method return path - "C:\Agent17-01\_work\50\Test Files"

Comment: HI @jeffrycopps  i used what you suggested. method return path C:\Agent17-01\_work\Test Files\

Comment: That is impossible. What is the FileName you are passing to the method? And from which directory are you running the script from ?

Comment: Thanks all for suggestion and solution.
I am able to find the solution and now it’s working.
When execution trigger on CI runtime available Tfs agent path like C:\Agent17-01\_work\50:
After that devops Getting s then final path build like that C:\Agent17-01\_work\50\s:
So in method I passed path File f=new File ("..\\..\\s\\Test Files\\"+FileName);
Then my method return C:\Agent17-01\_work\50\s\Test Files\fileName
What I want.
Thank you all again.

Answer (score 0):

Java accepts also "/" chars as directory dividers. Why is it important? - OS independence. My recomendation is to put the needed resource files into the src/main/resources folder, and then:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName).getFile();
```

this code would return you File instance, and you would be sure that it won't relies on absolute path. If you need just File path, and you are not gonna perform IO operations, use the method you've used (getCannonicalPath).

BTW: Please use Java code style while writing in Java: (brackets, parameters naming). I would recomend also to read about Try with Resources construction.